# Avoid duplicate field generated by JsonTypeInfo in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson Databind 2.7.2 and I have the following annotations on an interface:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubType1.class, name = "SubType1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubType2.class, name = "SubType2")})
public interface Common {
     String getType();
}
```

`getType` is overridden (implemented) in `SubType1` and `SubType2`. The problem is that when an instance of `SubType1` or `SubType2` is mapped to JSON it contain two fields called `type` with the same value:

```
{
  "type" : "SubType1",
  ... // Other properties
  "type" : "SubType1"
}
```

How can I prevent jackson from rendering duplicate fields?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Jackson renders type one time because you have told it to in the JsonTypeInfo annotation, then it renders it again because it sees a getter so it works its magic on `getType()` and adds another property. If you put a `@JsonIgnore` on the method in the interface it'll render it once:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubType1.class, name = "SubType1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubType2.class, name = "SubType2")})
public interface Common {
     @JsonIgnore
     String getType();
}
```

Produces:

```
{"type": "SubType1"}
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone happens to have this error, it can be solved by changing the default *include* property

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    visible = true,
    property = "type"
)
```

By default Jackson uses JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY

Reference: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html